# Need only Date from DateTime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date

I have a variable of DateTime type in SQL.
Just need to have Date part of it.

please Help?

Comment: In future please state the database engine and version you're using.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

The result is: “2009-07-14 00:00:00.000”

**Edit**: guess the next variant is more common:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

because of the `day` pattern can be easily changed to `week` or `month` pattern. It is very useful when the `GROUP BY` clause should group by week of month (reports).

Answer (score 5):

This has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688914/save-datetime-in-mssql-2005-without-hours-minutes-and-seconds) before on Stack Overflow.  In fact, it's been asked over and over:

1. [Most efficient way in MS SQL to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-ms-sql-to-get-date-from-datetime)
2. [Best way to check for current date in where clause of sql query.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325871/best-way-to-check-for-current-date-in-where-clause-of-sql-query)
3. [SQL Drop Time in DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493223/sql-drop-time-in-datetime)
4. [MS SQL Date Only Without Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467103/ms-sql-date-only-without-time)
5. [How to return the date part only from a SQL Server datetime datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype)

Answer (score 3):

Found this using [Google](http://www.google.com)

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())))

Comment: I do find this amusing, but does anyone really need a link to Google these days?  :-D

Comment: Some people apparently do :-D.

Comment: @tags2k & Colin:
I should say that I googled before putting my question here in stackoverflow but I didn't find any solution for my problem.
If you replace a datetime value with GETDATE() in your above query (and time part uses ب.ظ or ق.ظ at the end ) your query won't execute properly.  this is because I put the question here. Any way Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion converting to float is poor practice, because a round-trip conversion to datetime is not reliable. Please see [this post for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991).

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a varchar representation of the date, you can use the [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx) function, e.g.

```
select convert(varchar, getDate(), 102) /* 2009.07.14 */
```

If you need a datetime (midnight on the given date), you can just convert it back.

```
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getDate(), 102), 102)
```

Comment: COnverting to varchar and back is very slow.

Comment: @Alex that is true. Please see [this post with performance testing proving this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991).

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Sneaky CAST/DATEDIFF trick strips off the time to get just the day (midnight)!
CAST(DATEDIFF(d,0,DateField) AS DATETIME) AS DayField
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 has a date datatype that stores just the date, if you are inthis version, perhaps this would be a better datat type for you to use. Be warned though, Date doesn't work exactly like datetime for data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19900101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '19900101')
```

A very useful article:
"The purpose of this article is to explain how the datetime types work in SQL Server, including common pitfalls and general recommendations."[The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp)

Note that converting to varchar and back (convert(datetime, convert(varchar, getDate(), 102), 102)) is much slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the format 'MM/DD/YY', use "CONVERT(varchar, @datetimevalue, 1) to display just the date. If you need it in datetime format, use "CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, @datetimevalue, 1))".

I created an entry in my SQL blog about how to retrieve and display all possible formats of the CONVERT(varchar, ..) function:

http://jessesql.blogspot.com/2009/04/converting-datetime-values-to-varchar.html

Comment: Please note that converting dates to varchar is slower than using DateDiff and DateAdd. See [this post for more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991).

Answer (score 1):

A tip:
If you find yourself doing this often, you can create a scalar User Defined Function containing the time-stripping logic of your choice.

Be warned: SQL Server 2000 has some painful bugs involving UDF's in `ON` clauses.

Comment: Why scalar? Inline ones perform much better.

Comment: Very true. A deterministic CLR UDF may be even more efficient, but I've never tested this myself, and couldn't find anything through Google.

Comment: Using UDFs is convenient but poor practice because of it will kill  performance compared to proper queries.

Comment: I think it's a bit of an exaggeration to say it will "kill performance." There is a penalty, to be sure, but it is a small one. In this case, making a mistake in a delicate idiom is probably more expensive than conducting performance tests. In other words, proper profiling is a thousand times more important that worrying about hypothetical performance problems. I would say that eschewing tools that provide useful abstractions and help ensure correctness is "poor practice." SQL speed junkies may disagree.

Answer (score 0):

datepart(day, datetimevalue)

Comment: That only gives the day of the month, for example today is the 16th of July, so datepart(day, getdate()) would return 16.  I think he wants '2009-07-16' instead.

Comment: full syntax is datepart(Year|Day|Month|Hour|...., datetimevalue).

he can get the part and concart.....